# Set individual model values for select option inside ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to set models for each select option inside `*ngFor` but all are setting to same model value if I choose any option.

I tried to change the model value to `[(ngModel)]="data.selectedItem"` but the functionality of adding levels seems to break.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let data of levels;let index = index">
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" class="form-control input-sm custom-input-select">
      <option *ngFor="let value of columnValues">{{value}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Please find the plunker link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gldqpC?p=preview)

Comment: what supposes to be added to levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set SelectItem for each level:

```
 addLevel(){
    let data = {selectedItem:''}
    this.levels.push(data);
  }
```

then, as you manupulated the DOM inside the *nfFor, you have to set trackby option.

```
<div .... *ngFor="let data of levels;let index = index; trackBy: trackByFn">

<span (click)="addLevel()">Click to Add level</span>
```

and bind the model:

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="data.selectedItem" ....>
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/bLyVfSgNRfoBsQLdfr1A?p=preview)

Comment: add some value to `{selectedItem:''}` to avoid blank select

Answer (score 1):

add  value="{{value}}"inside option element :

```
<option *ngFor="let value of columnValues" value="{{value}}">{{value}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added [vaue]=value in option tag (DOM binding)

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let data of levels;let index = index">
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" class="form-control input-sm custom-input-select">
      <option *ngFor="let value of columnValues" [value]=value>{{value}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```